# Alternating patterns in 8b/10b encoding

Tags: clock, ethernet

I'm trying to evaluate the quality of an 8b/10b encoded data stream (Gigabit Ethernet, 1.25 gigabits/sec). Without doing clock recovery from the data stream, I want to measure jitter (et al) with a plain oscilliscope. Is there any 8b data stream I can send which ends up as a regular square wave in 10b format? I don't care it's divided or uneven duty cycle, as long as it's a regular grouping of 0's and 1's.

Comment: Wow. Are there really oscilloscopes out there that can visualize a 10 GHz signal? That's pretty impressing.

Comment: oops, wrote 1.25 gigabytes when I meant 1.25 gigabits.

Comment: But yeah, there are scopes that can do a really good job on 10Gig signaling. Anyone doing the latest PCI or 10Gig ethernet stuff needs them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternating patterns in 8b/10b encoding](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14379/alternating-patterns-in-8b-10b-encoding)

Comment: I doubt it because the running disparity calcs will keep selecting between different codes. Is there any testmode you can put the device into that you could use?

Comment: I think removing my PCS/PMA wrapper from my transceiver might be what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Alternating pattern for 8b10b encoding is D10.2 symbol. [Check out table in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding).

However this may not be what you want as for example gigabit Ethernet of the 1000BASE-T flavor uses PAM-5 modulation with data scrambling instead of NRZ with 8b10b encoding (again [Wikipedia is helpful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet)).

Also end result will depend in which protocol layer you are injecting test data as different protocol layers will add/remove/modify data.

Comment: My setup is a GMII interface to a PCS/PMA wrapper that directly drives a transceiver. Output is 1000Base-TX (for driving an optical SFP).

Comment: you should be ok then by driving d10.2 (010 01010)

Comment: You're right. I got distracted by your mention of PAM-5 and missed that you gave me the data word I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've found that the 10b words are selected specifically to avoid this kind of pattern. I looked at the 8b/10b tables for an hour or so before I gave up and determined it was going to have a very similar solution as the MU puzzle.

Comment: It is possible to achieve that kind of signal - it is right there in the table D10.2 D10=01010 and D.X.2=010 (EDCBA=01010 and HGF=010) and this is the same for both run disparities.

Comment: oh man, you're right. I don't know how many times I scanned the table (literally dozens) and missed that. Should've used a regular expression.